# Play 2, how to reuse a HTML code with a tag

Tags: templates, playframework-2.0

In Play! Framework v. 1.x there was such thing like a 'tag' where was possible to reuse some thml/template code.

In Play! Framework v 2.x, for me it is not clear still how it's going to be used ([here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplateUseCases)).

For example, I want to use tag to define a header for my site (in order not to repeat myself, but just include the header every in the pages where I need it).

Could someone explain me / show how to use tags, or whatever I should use to include the  header or any block of html/template code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You showed us a sample and you are asking for sample :)

That's easy, create a common view in `views.tags` package (remember to leave first line empty if you're not gonna to pass any params! also remember to add brackets after tags name):

**/app/views/tags/header.scala.html**

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

So you can 'include' it in any other view just with:

```
<body>
    @tags.header()
    Some other content
</body>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. 
I have this view in /app/views/tags/_pricing_plan.scala.html and when I try to 'include' it in another view in another package with `@tags._pricing_plan()` I just get `not found: value tags`