# How to reuse HTML in play framework

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the same question as in this accepted one. [Play 2, how to reuse a HTML code with a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772404/play-2-how-to-reuse-a-html-code-with-a-tag)
Only thing is that, This does not work for me. I have this view in /app/views/tags/_pricing_plan.scala.html and when I try to 'include' it in another view in another package with `@tags._pricing_plan()` I just get

```
not found: value tags
```

Comment: Before you'll try to use the tag for the first time in some view try to `play clean` and again `play ~run` sometimes Play requires some time for recognizing new packages/views/tags

Answer (score 0):

Each template is essentially compiled down to a function/class in the package you put the html. This means that to use it you must have it in scope (through an @import) or use the full name of the template including the package, just like regular Java or Scala code.

In addition to how it works in Java you can also use relative package names, since Scala allows this, so a template living in app.views could reference your fragment by calling it with @tags._pricing_plan() like you describe would work. But not if you are calling it from a template in some other package then it will point to thatpackage.tags which probably will not exist.

So either use fully qualified name views.tags._pricing_plan or import it to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing a header on `_pricing_plan.scala.html`. If you have no passed in values, you need a @() header.